# Getting Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, microsoft-office

I am having great trouble getting:
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word
and
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Core

I am trying to run my program on another laptop and it needs these files.

I downloaded and installed the Microsoft Office PIA and I cannot find the DLL files anywhere.

The files are not in the .NET or COM list when I go to "add reference"

In the laptops assembly I can find microsoft.office.interop.word, but I cannot find the DLL.

The program has microsoft.office.excel.dll as i was able to transfer this file from my other computer. I could not do this with core or word though.

Does anybody know what I can do?

Comment: By "your program" do you mean a program you wrote yourself?  In which language?

Comment: @The Dude, Does your laptop have Office installed?